# AngularJS, не передается $http в components

Tags: angularjs, http, post

Всем привет, изучаю AngularJS(1.6), при вызове post метода выдает ошибку

> Can not read property 'post' of undefined

Использую компоненты.
в параметрах контроллера передаю $http, возможно проблема в области видимости

Код компоненты

```js
 .component('myContent', {
    template: '<button type="button" class="btn btnBuy btn-info btn-lg btn-default" ng-click="$ctrl.open($event)">Buy now</button>',
    controller: ['$uibModal','$http', function($uibModal,$http) {
  var $ctrl = this;

      $ctrl.open = function($event) {
        var parent = $event.currentTarget.parentNode.parentNode;
        var parentPrice = " ";
         parentPrice = parent.querySelector('div.price').innerHTML;
   
         var priceProduct = parentPrice.match(/\D+:\s*\$\s*([\d.]+)/g);
       
         var nameProduct = parent.querySelector('span').innerHTML;
         var imgProduct = parent.querySelector('img').src.replace(/http:\/\/localhost:3000/g, '') ;

         console.log(priceProduct);
       
   $ctrl.dataForModal = {
        price: priceProduct,
        name: nameProduct,
        img: imgProduct,
        email: 'someEmail@gmail.com'
      }

     
        $uibModal.open({
          component: "myModal",
          resolve: {
            modalData: function() {
              return $ctrl.dataForModal;
            }
          }
        }).result.then(function(result,$http) {
          console.info("I was closed, so do what I need to do myContent's controller now.  Result was->");
          //console.info(result);
          console.info($ctrl.dataForModal);
        
     $http.post('/api/product', $ctrl.dataForModal).
      success(function(res) {
        console.info("vse ok");
      }).
      error(function(res) {
        console.info('error');
      });
                        
        }, function(reason) {
          console.info("I was dimissed, so do what I need to do myContent's controller now.  Reason was->" + reason);
        });
      };
    }] 
       
  });
```

Comment: убери `$http` отсюда: `.result.then(function(result,$http) {`

Answer (score 0):

Так как вызов находится внутри

```
.result.then(function(result,$http) { ... })
```

`$http` внутри будет тем, что установят внутри `result`. Но так как, в данном случае, `$http` не передается - его значение внутри функции будет `undefined`.

Для решения нужно убрать этот параметр:

```
.result.then(function(result) { ... })
```

Тогда значение будет браться из параметров основной функции, куда подставляется с помощью DI